# VBA, Compile Error, Expected Array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run my code, getting a compile error. 
Currently I am struggling trying to optimize my code because I read that I need to use Variant more and not access workbooks in loop. Currently if I run without changes it takes very long.  For this question i shortened my code alot, can provide full if needed.

I am getting stuck on this line, `thisArr(i - 1, 1) = thisArr(i - 1, 1) & "|" & sourceWS(i, readcols(j))`

```
Public Sub generateIRandCRshocks(scenPath As String, scenNames() As Variant, curveNameToMarketData() As Variant, curveData() As Variant, curveNames() As Variant, currToRiskFree() As Variant, termBuckets() As Variant, exportPath As String)

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim thisScen As Long, thisCurve As Long, thisBucket As Long
Dim lastrow As String, thisRow As Long
Dim thisArr() As Variant
Dim thisArrRow As Long, thisCurveMapRow As Long, thisCurveDataRow As Long, thisRiskFreeRow As Long

Dim sourceWB As Variant
Dim sourceWS As String
Dim lastWSrow As Variant
Dim lastcol As String




    lastrow = lastWSrow(sourceWS) 
    lastcol = 20
    sourceWS = sourceWB.Worksheets(scenNames(thisScen, 1)).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol))

  'read into array and concatenate attribute columns
    ReDim thisArr(1 To lastrow - 1, 1 To 4)
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        j = 1
            thisArr(i - 1, 1) = sourceWS(i, readcols(j))
        For j = 2 To 7
            thisArr(i - 1, 1) = thisArr(i - 1, 1) & "|" & sourceWS(i, readcols(j))
        Next j
        j = 8
            thisArr(i - 1, 2) = sourceWS(i, readcols(j))
        j = 9
            thisArr(i - 1, 3) = sourceWS(i, readcols(j))
        j = 2
            thisArr(i - 1, 4) = sourceWS(i, readcols(j)) 'currency entered again in its own column for easy lookup later
    Next i
```

Comment: I am not seeing where you declare and assign value to the array `readcols`

Comment: `sourceWS` is a string. You are trying to index it like a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

`ReadCols` is not declared at all, and `SourceWS` is delcared as a String rather than an array, like you are referring to it.

Perhaps you meant:

```
Dim SourceWS as Variant, ReadCols as Variant
```

or

```
Dim SourceWS() as String, ReadCols() as String
```

If you're assigning a worksheet range to the array, it will need to be a variant.

---

Unrelated observation:

This is just creating extra lines of code unnecessarily:

```
  j = 8
        thisArr(i - 1, 2) = sourceWS(i, readcols(j))
```

...instead of simply:

```
thisArr(i-1, 2) = sourceWS(i, readcols(8))
```